# Community favors Sharepoint questions

Tags: discussion, community, bookmarks

Noted at [Meta.Mathematics.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9788/bounty-by-community#comment35928_9789) the [Community User](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=favorites) seem to favor a lot of SharePoint questions.

Why is that? This doesn't look nominal...

Comment: A deleted user who had lots of favorites on SharePoint is the most likely reason. Community takes over deleted accounts.